# Is there anyway to use multiple datasets in the same report?

Tags: powerbi

I have datasets that have RLS built into them, and report builders who want to consume that data AND also consume additional data sources like SPO lists, Excel files, etc..

I don't see any way that PBI will allow more than one datasource to be used in a report.

If I give the report creators the actual datasource file to open they can bypass all the RLS, so I don't see anyway around this?

Will I have to deploy a RLS dataset and then also include whatever external data they want inside the actual dataset and then deploy it for them to consume?

Comment: Do your users have pro licenses, are are you on premium capacity? If so, all you need to do is add those data sources to the data model on your pbix file and republish, but MAKE SURE you make the "Apply security filters in both directions" set to true in the relationships tab, otherwise your RLS won't carry through if the tables are related.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  
I was hoping I could allow the users to consume the datasets (data models) I published that have RLS but then add their own data sources to it inside PBI.

In this case, it appears that is not possible so I'll have to do as you suggested.

That means I'll need a copy of each dataset for every new item they want to join in with it.

Comment: Yes, this is more of a data governance issue. In this case, I'd sit my main data model on the workspace, and tell them to use their own PBIX files to use the published data model as the source. I'm not sure if the RLS will carry through, that's an interesting case I never thought about, but I would err on the side of caution and say it won't. I can definitely see an efficiency gain there. I think that you will end up needing to create several data-marts, one for each business unit or segregated user group, so that there is no chance for sensitive data to get into the wrong hands.

Comment: Furthermore, once they have their own PBIX files attached to your model, you can then guide them through the process of adding whatever excel file they're using to track their special data. I would recommend hosting it online rather than on their laptops. PBI has functionality to put excel workbooks directly inside the workspace, where they can be used as a datasource.